# I need a fast approach to search substrings

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I'm reworking a framework and I need a fast algorithm to search for a substring in a collection of strings.

In short, a class is alerted when any event from a child association is triggered.

The event contains a path which is the path from the current class to the event that was triggered (usually a property change).

Each class has static bindings to paths that are loaded in a collection.
A binding consist of the actual path and a set of property names that are binded to the said path.

When a class receives an event it needs to check if any property name is binded to the event's path and triggers something on any property that has a binding.

Now, I'm only looking for the best collection type to store these bindings and the best way to search the event's path within the static bindings.

Right now my implementation is really basic. I am using a HashMap the key being the possible paths while the value is a set of properties binded to the path.

I am looping through the keyset and I use startsWith with the event's path. (The event's path needs to be a substring of a binding starting from index 0)

For exemple a path would look like this : "association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2" or "association1.association2.association3"

The binding map would look this this (not actually initialised like this it's just an example) :

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> bindings = new HashMap<>();
{
    bindings.put("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2", new HashSet<>());
    bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property1");
    bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property2");
    bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property3");

    bindings.put("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3", new HashSet<>());
    bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property4");
    bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property5");
    bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property6");
    bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property7");
}
```

So for a class with these bindings, receiving an event with a path like "association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3" or "association1.association2.association3"
Would both need to trigger something on property4, property5, property6 and property7.

Like I said, what I need is the most efficient way to search which properties (if any) are binded to an event's path.

I use Java 8 so I don't mind using lambda or whatever is available.
Reworking the bindings as collection of strings of any other format is not out of the question neither if it helps.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe im understanding this all wrong, but wouldn't a tree or a graph be a much better representation of all of this? then you just use DFS/BFS to resolve any of this without string operations.

Comment: It might be, the thing is, bindings are generated by a tool that analyses the use of properties through a pretty strict framework so bindings can only be static string paths. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all the replies but I've changed my approach.

I will still use a HashMap but instead of adding :

- "association1.association2.property"

and try to match partial keys i will add:

- "association1"
- "association1.association2"
- "association1.association2.property"

This way I can efficiently use the hash and since the bindings are static and generated only once for each class type, changing the algorithm of the generation has no performance cost at all.

Thanks again for all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say

> I am looping through the keyset and I use startsWith with the event's path. (The event's path needs to be a substring of a binding starting from index 0)

You should consider using a different data structure.  A `HashMap` provides for efficient *whole-key* lookups, but it doesn't help much at all for partial-key lookups.  You could consider instead using a `SortedMap` such as `TreeMap`. For `String` keys, `SortedMap.tailMap()` or `SortedMap.subMap()` will help you navigate directly to the keys you're looking for, if they are present.

Of course, insertions, deletions, and whole-key lookups are less efficient in a `TreeMap` than in a `HashMap` (on average); this is a tradeoff against the much better efficiency of key substring searching.

Comment: I think it might be exactly what I need. I'll benchmark some test and let you know if it solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a Stream API approach:

```
String path = "association1.association2.association3";
List<Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>> result = 
  bindings.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(path))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is just a different way to write what the OP describes already doing.  It's more compact and probably clearer, but there's no reason to think that it will be any more efficient.

Comment: You are right - it surely can be faster if everthing is implemented in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Parallel Stream or to implement your own Map.

Here the tests:

## Solution proposed by John (TreeMap)

The best: 6 millliseconds

```
String path = "association1.association2.association3";
            TreeMap<String, HashSet> bindings2 = new TreeMap<String, HashSet>(new Comparator<String>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    if (o1.equals(o2))
                        return 0;
                    if (o1.startsWith(o2))
                        return 1;
                    return -1;
                }
            });
            {
                bindings2.put("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2", new HashSet<>());
                bindings2.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property1");
                bindings2.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property2");
                bindings2.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property3");

                bindings2.put("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3", new HashSet<>());
                bindings2.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property4");
                bindings2.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property5");
                bindings2.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property6");
                bindings2.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property7");
            }

            // test 1
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Object result1 =  bindings2.tailMap(path).entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(path))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
            System.out.println(result1);
```

## Solution proposed by Stefan (Stream)

The best: 16 millliseconds

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> bindings = new HashMap<>();
            {
                bindings.put("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2", new HashSet<>());
                bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property1");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property2");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property3");

                bindings.put("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3", new HashSet<>());
                bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property4");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property5");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property6");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property7");
            }

            // test 1
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String path = "association1.association2.association3";
            List<Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>> result =  bindings.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(path)).collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

            result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

## Solution proposed by Me (parallel Stream)

The best: 9 millliseconds

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> bindings = new HashMap<>();
            {
                bindings.put("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2", new HashSet<>());
                bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property1");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property2");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.propertyInAssociation2").add("property3");

                bindings.put("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3", new HashSet<>());
                bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property4");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property5");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property6");
                bindings.get("association1.association2.association3.propertyInAssociation3").add("property7");
            }
            // test 1
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String path = "association1.association2.association3";
            List<Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>> result = bindings.entrySet().stream().parallel()
                    .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(path)).collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

            result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Tests are not reliable with few data. Personally I prefer the solution proposed by Fred.

**UPDATE**: as suggested by Dodgy here you can find a more formal test using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

https://github.com/venergiac/benchmark-jmh

```
git clone https://github.com/venergiac/benchmark-jmh.git
mvn install
java -jar target\benchmark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and the tests revealed a better throughput on parallel stream with hashmap, but we should perform these test on a more formal environlment with more time.

Comment: A few issues here. "Fred's solution" is John Bollinger's solution. He proposes using tailMap or subMap, but the code you've timed doesn't. Also, you shouldn't use currentTimeMillis() for benchmarking - Google Java microbenchmarking and use the recommended techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the reply this is pretty comprehensive! But like I've said I changed my approach to this problem. Also Fred is me the OP.

Comment: Personally I prefer your more structured solution, but after few tests with 200000 items, it seems that your original solution with parallel stream is better than the other one.
Sometime dirty solution is better, since allocate less memory and can leverage on powerfull of string....or my benchmark tests are wrong....